# In a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN'

Tags: iframe, popup, display

```
<a href="#popupVideo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">Launch video player</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupVideo" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="a" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
    <iframe src="https://xxxx.net" width="497" height="298" seamless=""></iframe>
</div>
```

I am trying to add an iframe in the pop up window but its showing me the error 
In a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN, SAMEORIGIN'.

What to do now  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by changing the file httpd.conf

```
<IfModule headers_module> 
 <IfVersion >= 2.4.7 > 
  Header always setifempty X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
 </IfVersion>
 <IfVersion < 2.4.7 > 
  Header always merge X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN 
 </IfVersion> 
 RequestHeader unset Proxy 
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `https://xxxx.net`'s owner doesn't want anyone to iFrame his resources on their websites.

If that domain is yours and you want to include its content into another your website, you should whitelist it using `ALLOW-FROM https://your-domain.com`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Downvoted, as this is an obsolete directive that no longer works in modern browsers. Best not to use it.